# How to control with a mouse click in Wolfram Cloud?

Tags: cloud, mouseclick

I would like to publish 'NIM GAME' written as follows on Wolfram Cloud.

```
title = "NIM GAME"; 
{iwon, youwon} = {"You Lose!", "You Win!"};
coin = Module[{i}, {EdgeForm[], 
Table[{GrayLevel[Sin[\[Pi] i/0.9]], 
  Polygon[{{i, 0}, {i + 0.05, 0}, {i + 0.05, 0.3}, {i, 
     0.3}}]}, {i, 0, 0.9, 0.05}], EdgeForm[Thick], 
Line[{{0, 0}, {0.9, 0}, {0.9, 0.3}, {0, 0.3}}]}];  
move[stack_] := Module[{nn, id, p, q, a, b},
  id = Map[IntegerDigits[#, 2, 10] &, stack];
  nn = Mod[Plus @@ id, 2];
  p = Position[nn, 1];
  {a, b} = First[If[p == {}, {#, # - 1} & /@ Select[stack, # > 0 &], Select[Map[FromDigits[#, 2] & /@ {#, Mod[nn + #, 2]} &, id], Last[#] < First[#] &]]];
  q = Position[stack, a][[1, 1]];
  ReplacePart[stack, q -> b]];
Manipulate[ If[ng, stack = RandomInteger[{1, mnc}, ns]; ng = False; 
  m = Max[stack]; myTurn = True];
 Pane[ If[Plus @@ stack == 0, If[myTurn, iwon, youwon],
Framed@ClickPane[
 Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thin], Black, 
   Table[Translate[coin, {i, 0.35 j}], {i, Length[stack]}, {j, 
     stack[[i]]}], 
   Text[Style[If[myTurn, "Your ", "My "] <> "turn...", Red, 
     "SubTitle", 16], {3, 0.16}]}, Background -> LightYellow, 
  PlotRange -> {{0.9, 1.1 + Length[stack]}, {0.01, 0.6 + 0.35 m}},
   ImageSize -> {500, 300}],
 If[myTurn, {i, j} = {Floor[#[[1]]], Floor[(#[[2]] - 0.35)/0.35]};
    If[0 <= j < stack[[i]], stack[[i]] = j; myTurn = False], 
   stack = move[stack]; myTurn = True] &]]  , {500, 400}, Alignment -> {Center, Center}], {stack, ControlType -> None}, {{ns, 4, "number of stacks"}, Range[3, 6], ControlType -> Setter}, 
{{mnc, 4, "maximum number of coins"}, Range[2, 10],
ControlType -> Setter}, {{ng, True, "new game"}, {True, False}}, SaveDefinitions -> True, TrackedSymbols -> Manipulate]
```

This code works well with CDF. However, it does not work with Wolfram Cloud. Doesn't seem to support mouse clicks.

[wolfram cloud page](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/675f561c-b403-4a42-8c48-0aebfa79a466)

How to control with a mouse click in Wolfram Cloud?

The important thing is that it should be able to operate on smartphones (android).

If mouse click is not possible in Wolfram Cloud, I want another roundabout way.